# Exact count of coprimes of $n$ up to $x < n$

Tags: number-theory

We know that the count of positive integers up to a given integer $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$ is [Euler's totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) or $\varphi(n)$ function:

$$\varphi(n) = n(1 - 1/p_1)(1 - 1/p_2)\ldots(1 - 1/p_k)$$
where $p_i$ are the distinct primes dividing $n$.

But what is the count of positive integers relatively prime to $n$ up to *another* integer $x \leq n$? Does it have a name? Not knowing any better, I call it $\varphi(n,x)$ below.

We can express $\varphi(n,x)$ as a function of all the possible subsets of the distinct primes of $n$ using the principle of [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

\begin{array}{rl}
\varphi(n, x) = & x \\ 
 & - \left \lfloor x/p_1 \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor x/p_2 \right \rfloor \ldots - \left \lfloor x/p_k \right \rfloor \\ 
& + \left \lfloor x/(p_1 p_2) \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor x/(p_1 p_3) \right \rfloor \ldots + \left \lfloor x/(p_{k-1}p_k) \right \rfloor \\  
& - \left \lfloor x/(p_1 p_2 p_3) \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor x/(p_1 p_2 p_4) \right \rfloor \ldots - \left \lfloor x/(p_{k-2}p_{k-1}p_k) \right \rfloor \\ 
 & \ldots 
\end{array}

Even skipping all the terms where $p_i p_j ... p_l > x$ (since the floor function will null them anyway), there are still lots of terms.

Of course, it is easy to demonstrate that $\varphi(n,n) = \varphi(n)$ (in fact, I think that is the proof for the expression of $\varphi(n)$ above). Initially, I naïvely thought that we could express it as a function very similar to $\varphi(n)$, e.g. along the lines of:

$$\bigg \lfloor \Big \lfloor \big \lfloor x (p_1 -  1)/p_1 \big \rfloor (p_2 -  1)/p_2 \Big \rfloor \ldots (p_k -  1)/p_k \bigg \rfloor.$$

But all my attempts so far have failed (including uses of $\text{gcd}(n, x)$, applying the floor function on different parts, accumulating remainders, etc.). Is there a simpler algorithm to calculate exactly $\varphi(n, x)$ than the one that iterates through all subsets of primes (the ones whose product is no greater than $x$)?

Comment: $\varphi(n)$ is *not* the number of divisors of $n$; it is the number of integers $0<k<n$ which are *coprime* to $n$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function.

Comment: @KentaS good catch, thank you; I corrected the question.

Comment: @StevenClark I don't immediately see how either $D(x)$ or $d(x)$ can be used here.

Comment: Basically no, there's no simpler exact formula. There are approximations that are pretty good if you're willing to settle for an approximation in the first place, namely $\phi(n) \frac xn$. (And I think $\phi(n,x)$ is actually the usual notation for this function, so well done there!)

Comment: @GregMartin thank you! I was starting to surmise just as much (no simpler formula). If you convert your comment to an answer I can uptick and accept.

Comment: For "special" $x$ what @GregMartin suggests as an approximation can be made exact.  Consider for example $x = n/2$. Now $y$ is coprime to $n$ if and only if $n-y$ is coprime to $n$, so $\phi(n,n/2) = \phi(n)/2$.